# Spinner / Loader in TinyMCE's content until fetch finishes

Tags: javascript, ajax, tinymce, textarea

I am using generative AI to fetch content from ChatGPT API.
How do I include a loading animation or a spinner of sorts until my AJAX function returns the data to be inserted into the tinymce textarea ?

```
document.getElementById('btn-elementID').addEventListener('click', (event) =>
{
    document.getElementById('elementID').value = "Please wait while we re-generate this section...";
    tinymce.get('elementID').setContent("Please wait while we re-generate this section...");

    getAnswer('elementID').then((body) =>
    {
        document.getElementById('elementID').value = body.answer;
        tinymce.get('elementID').setContent(body.answer);
    });
});
```